# Choose when otherwise is reordering my list of objects

Tags: java, jsp

I have a `comments` objects with the following properties `created, submittedBy, comment, deleted and deletedBy`. I'm testing to see if a comment is flagged as being deleted in a `JSP` page

```
<c:forEach var="comment" items="${comments}" >
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty comment.deleted}">
            <i style="font-size:10px;">deleted</i>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            ${comment.text}
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <hr />
</c:forEach>
```

Before I added the `choose when otherwise conditions`, all comments displayed in descending order using the `datetime` field `created`

comment 5 
comment 4
comment 3
comment 2
comment 1

Now that I did add the conditions to check for deleted, my list is reordered. For example, if I flag comment 3 and 4 as deleted, the following will happen -

comment 4
comment 3
comment 5
comment 2
comment 1

Why is the order being changed by introducing the `choose when otherwise`? and how can I make it so it doesn't reorder? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, like how you're retrieving the comments. A conditional has no way of reordering a collection.

Comment: Did you a typo in the code? What kind of collection you use?

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, what you said makes sense. I've been focusing on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:forEach var="comment" items="${comments}" >
  ${qaComment.deleted == ''?qaComment.comment:'deleted'}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: yea, I have used it for check box nd such. Should work, haven't tested.

Comment: Can you test it right now? Extra quotes in `'qaComment.comment'`?

Comment: good call, the quote make it littreal rather than evaluating as expression. Updated thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Ok, so having quote surrounding the attribute makes it just literal like it just prints the word "qaComment.comment" instead of evaluating to a value. Without single quote it's evaluated to a actual value.

Comment: @Sas that does simplify things quite a bit, thanks for posting that. The order still changes and as mentioned in comment, will have to focus on how the collection is being retrieved. Going to close this case because I've asked the wrong question